# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
update test as t 
SET t.agent=86 
where t.id in (select tgt.test_id from test_group_tests as tgt where tgt.test_id in 
(select t.id from test where t.agent in (1)) and tgt.testgroup_id not in (20,58,23,37,447));
```

I tried this query and I see this error. Is it missing inner join or something?

Answer (score 2):

In general, MySQL won't allow you to `SELECT` a table and `UPDATE` the same table in the same query. You can, however, write a multi-table `UPDATE` by joining tables.

The way I read your query, it seems like the following would do the same thing:

```
UPDATE test AS t
JOIN test_group_test AS tgt ON (t.id=tgt.test_id)
JOIN test AS t2 ON (tgt.test_id=t2.id)
SET t.agent=86
WHERE t2.agent IN (1)
  AND tgt.testgroup_id NOT IN (20,58,23,37,447);
```

Though I have not tested this query. It's meant as an example of using `JOIN` for a multi-table `UPDATE`. So test it yourself carefully to see if it does what you intend, and keep a backup of your original data in case it doesn't.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html for more on multi-table `UPDATE` in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfect. I had some duplicates entries but had to add them to NOT IN clause to run my query.  I learned new thing using JOIN in "multi table"

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, the subquery will return all test id's not in the groups (20,58,23,37,447), but the update will only update the test records where agent is in (1).

```
update test as t 
SET t.agent=86 
where t.agent in (1)
and t.id in 
(
   select
   tgt.test_id
   from test_group_tests as tgt 
   where tgt.testgroup_id not in (20,58,23,37,447)
);
```